# server.mappath not working in asp.net after publish

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have used server.mappath() in my application.It is working fine in debug mode,but after publishing into IIS it is not working.

```
string filePath=Path.Combine(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("/calendar"),
                             "MonthCalendarTest.exe");
Process.Start(filePath, Convert.ToString(LoggedInUserKey));
```

Tried with absolute path,

```
"../../calendar/MonthCalendarTest.exe" 
"~/calendar/MonthCalendarTest.exe".
```

Please let me know where i am going wrong.

Comment: This may well be a security issue rather than a mappath issue. What error message do you recieve? I have never seen someone fire an exe from an IIS process without changing a lot of security settings

Comment: This is the error message i am getting "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified"

Answer (score 0):

I guess this could be wild card issue, because after publishing website to IIS, it allow only those extensions to run which are mapped in the IIS. Please check the same.